# Listener problem in extendedDataTable with rows="10"

Tags: datatable, listener, richfaces, rows

I have a problem with the extendedDataTable in richfaces. Below there is the code

```
<rich:extendedDataTable id="dt2_documenti_a4" styleClass="tableLeft"
            rowClasses="row1,row2" rows="10" value="#{formCarriBombolaiDettaglioInterventoBean.elencoErogazioni}" var="doc"
            selectionMode="single" selection="#{formCarriBombolaiDettaglioInterventoBean.selection}"> 

            <a4j:ajax execute="dt2_documenti_a4" event="selectionchange" listener="#{carriBombolaiPMIBean.updateCheckboxErogazioneEvPub()}" 
                        render="dt2_documenti_a4, calcoli_preventivo_ev_pub, mod_preventivo, panel_preventivi"/>
```

Now, the code works well untill I change the page. To explain better, there is the list `elencoErogazioni` that has 29 elements, and because the number of rows is setted to 10, there are 3 pages of the table. Whene I go to the page 2 (or 3) the listener doesn't work anymore. I can't select any row and I don't know why. Someone of you know what the problem could be?

Comment: What do you mean by "can't select a row"? Does nothing happen on the client-side?

Comment: Yes that's the problem

Comment: No error in the console? If the row doesn't highlight then either there's an error in the event handling or the click is not reaching the table in the first place.

Comment: No there is no error in the console.